# Can disease, drugs, or other physiological conditions violate the all-or-none rule for action potential?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, electrophysiology, drugs

We are taught that the amplitude of a neuron's spike is always the same (within a negligibly small range)--all or none. But it seems that anomalous physiological conditions like certain diseases or drugs might cause neurons to violate the all-or-none rule. Similarly, I wonder if in EBS, the spikes have greater amplitude. Can anyone tell me of any specific conditions that alter spike amplitude?

Comment: Welcome. What is EBS? Can you add sources that make you suspect the effect of this EBS on APs?

Comment: Thank you, Alice. Electric brain stimulation. I don't have a source; it just seems that if the voltage of the stimulation is greater, that would affect the amplitudes of the APs of the local neurons.